Does division into training, validation, and test sets make p-hacking impossible?
Is it possible to commit "statistical sins" such as

stopping data exploration if an analysis yields a significant p-value

deciding whether to include or drop outliers postanalyses


when using machine learning algorithms? In other words, does division into training,validation, and test sets make p-hacking impossible?

If you use  an algorithm that someone else wrote and you use it  "out of the box" then, if it was written to avoid these sins, you will avoid them.  But you can create an algorithm that sins.

Any misinterpretation/mistake you can do in a "traditional" study can also be done when looking at the test set for a machine learning activity. The mistakes may differ a bit because different things get "traditionally" done in different types of studies, but there's lots of similarities, too e.g.

Something very close to "p-hacking" would be repeated iteration and re-evaluation on the same test set until the results on the test set looks good.
There's also "random seed hacking". It has been suggested that ML papers "happen to have" a particularly lucky seed value (in the sense that model training is somewhat random for many algorithms like neural networks and performance may look particularly good if you evaluate vs. the test set for many different seeds) more often than is likely to occur solely by chance.
Along the same lines, you have problems, if instead of evaluating a single algorithm we picked based on the training/validation data once, we select 10 and try them all on the test set. This introduces all the usual multiplicity issues and exaggerates the performance of the best one you pick based on the test set.
Or, people might pick the performance metric that shows their new approach to look best.
You decide to exclude some data from the test set, because performance does not look good on some subset of data, similar to excluding data based on results in some normal study.
Misinterpretations of p-values (or confidence intervals) of test set performance (or not using any statistics on the test set and just saying that higher performance on some metric on the test set = proven better performance) are similar to those seen in traditional studies.
Lack of pre-specification: One of the potential safeguards against post-hoc changes is pre-registration of methods, which is very uncommon in machine learning (but more common in some fields, e.g. clinical trials). Very often nobody knows whether what a ML paper reports in the end is what the authors started out trying to do and/or how much they changed their evaluation approach along the way.

And, of course, machine learning, as well as train-validation-test splitting offers additional opportunities to make mistakes, e.g.

Interpreting variable/feature importance as a test / p-value / confirmation that something is important
Mis-interpreting performance on a hold-out test set from the same data source (e.g. same hospital and X-ray machine from which all training data came) as proving generalizable real-world performance (including in different hospitals, using different X-ray machines and in totally different countries/healthcare systems).
Leaking test data somehow (e.g. training on all the internet when the test data is out there, too, missing data imputation before train/validation/test splitting, splitting where different versions of the same data point end up in different sets post-data-augmentation, not respecting past-vs.-future splitting for target embeddings, not splitting past-vs.-future and leaking information indirectly...)
Unsuitable data (e.g. the famous example of all those COVID-19 detection models that used adult COVID-19 patient X-rays and trained a classifier to distinguish them from non-COVID-19 X-rays from children)
blind application of (possibly unsuitable) models
addressing the wrong question/using an inappropriate performance metric

Of course, some of these issues are just sloppy work (unless they are intentional), but it doesn't help that there is limited use of reporting standards / transparency / requirements to share underlying data.
So, from some perspective, machine learning algorithm research could be seen as more complicated (at least in some respects) than some other types of research and as more vulnerable to issues. I don't want to exaggerate this and trying to prevent overfitting to your training data from skewing your hyperparameter tuning and model evaluation (one of the goals of training-validation-test splitting), is definitely an important thing to aim for.

But why would not all the points made in the first part of your post (from "repeated iteration and re-evaluation" to "Lack of pre-specification") be completely addressed and solved by valid splitting into training-validation-test sets ?

because people tend to peek at the test sets (so just same as p-hacking). see eg kaggle competitions, where public "leaderboards" encourage people to iterate to get higher on test ( and similarly for other ML competitions). ideally the test set is owned by a different person and performance of ML model on test set evaluated only once. "valid" is doing a lot of heavy lifting.

infamous example of "Lack of pre-specification" is taking a new ML model and trying it on a whole bunch of standard ML data sets until you find one dataset (with valid splitting) for which you get best results.

@seanv507  You say that "valid" splitting of the sets involves a lot of heavy lifting. But what else is required besides looking  exactly once at the test data  ?

If you can enforce in general (i.e. not just for the one project where you are the ultimately in charge CEO of the company that can enforce whatever they want) that people look exactly once, great. Now try to do that for things where the test set is available to anyone on the internet. Do you believe everyone only looks once? This article on test (and validation) sets is great.

Problems I've seen:

people try to predict based on what what happens to patients x months into the future, some of the future months of the patients are in the training data. E.g. for patient #1 month 1 to 11, as well as 13 to 24, and some in the test data (e.g. month 12). A model might do well, because it "recognizes" the patient and just interpolates between month 11 and 13 to predict 12, but in practice you don't know the future.
People do missing data imputation or feature engineering before train/test split and accidentally leak the target across records.



People do things on the test set that leaks the target (e.g. missing data imputation in a way that uses the target)
The test set is so small that the evaluation is unreliable/noisy, even if you only do it once.
The test data doesn't evaluate the real life setting (because maybe the training data doesn't exactly either), e.g. it doesn't really test generalization (due to being all from the same hospital, with the same X-ray machine, from mild patients etc. when in real-life people want to generalize more widely).
...
I could continue this list for a long time.


i am not sure if you understood my comment. i meant "valid" is covering a lot of different areas ( basically covered in this answer and the comments). your question sounds like does "valid data splitting avoid the problems of invalid hypothesis testing(ie p-hacking)". and i am saying the issue is with cheating, whether you split data or do hypothesis testing
